Do we need 10 parmita to attain Nirvana?
Do we need 10 Parmita for attaining Nirvana?
or is it that 10 parmitas  are for becoming buddha?

Which tradition specifically do these ten paramitas far under? For example, Mahayana, Theravada or there is no specification.

its not doing. but talked about many time. specificaly burmies tradition. goenka.

It appears that both Burmese and Goenka refers to the Theravada tradition.

yes its Theravada

U should explain what u mean by Buddha

I means samyak sambuddha in future and bodhisatva now.

Paramitas hold the purpose of cultivating the qualities necessary for enlightenment. But enlightenment itself requires understanding of Dhamma. Enlightenment requires being dispassionate towards the five aggregates because they are not Self. In other words , cessation of ignorance is enlightenment. Or we can say enlightenment is cessation of greed , aversion and delusion.

We actually need 10 paramithas to gain nirvana. They have to be completed in our past lives or in this life. But a great lord buddha have to complete 30 paramithas in order to gain enlightenment.
